# Setting up a sandbox dev environment for Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, development-environment

I am planning to get Sharepoint (MOSS) setup on my home development workstation and one of the things I read about using virtualisation (I currently have Vista, need Windows Server) is that you can install VMs with different OS's (eg Vista, Server) or you can run one OS with the ability to do development on Sharepoint/MS CRM etc which is sandboxed (Can't effect the OS).

My pc specs: Intel Quad Core 2.4ghz, 4GB RAM, Vista 32-bit (so I can't see/use all 4gbs).

How is this usually setup?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

This article has everything you need. It covers essential post-installation tasks such as server configuration.

[How to Create a MOSS 2007 VPC Image: The Whole 9 Yards](http://www.pptspaces.com/sharepointreporterblog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=28)

Answer (score 3):

Just want to point out that there are more problems with 32-bit SharePoint than the fact that you can’t use all your memory. Read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2008/10/03/64-bit-and-the-admin-toolkit-download-trend.aspx) blog post for more info. I guess you are talking about SharePoint 2007, but 2010 is around the corner and its 64-bit only (probably due to the problems described in that blog post). So I'd recommend you to do it properly and set up an x64 environment from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download a virtualization software.  Virtual PC, Virtual Server, VMWare Server are popular and free
2. Install according to the instructions.
3. Create a virtual machine (it is usually a wizard)
4. Install a OS and configure manually, or you can download a use an existing virtual hard drive.

Microsoft Offers one you can use.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=67f93dcb-ada8-4db5-a47b-df17e14b2c74&DisplayLang=en

Comment: Except Virtual PC doesn't support 64-bit development :(

Comment: Lack of 64bit support is only a problem for 2010 right?  I frequently dev and receive end user training in MOSS 2007 with the setup I described.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to copy an existing virtual image from the company network and run that image at home. 
If you don't have any existing images at the company you can create one using the "physical to VM" option in VMware workstation / Virtual server and then clone an existing server.

Remember that you might need to create a library of images if you have to test code on an box with SP1, SP2, June Cumulative and so on.
[this](https://serverfault.com/questions/18290/virtual-machine-guest-optimization-tips) post on ServerFault is a nice guide to max the performance of the image.

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to add the following to other great answers:

- Use Windows 2008 Hyper-V as your host operating system. In my case it had much better performance than Vista on same machine
- In case you plan to develop for SharePoint+CRM there is [MS prepared virtual machine](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=dd939ed9-87a5-4c13-b212-a922cc02b469&displaylang=en) with both. Unfortunately it is available on to MBS partners. [SharePoint only machine](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=67f93dcb-ada8-4db5-a47b-df17e14b2c74&displaylang=en) is publicly available. Both machines will expire after 30 days, but just apply your product key and you will prolong it's life for additional year.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Windows Server 2008 directly on my laptop, so no need for VMs. It's an x64 machine as well. I use SQL server 2008 as well. It's just easier than running VMs and believe me, you need the full 4 GB if you are running Vista. Just install the x64 version of Win2008 on your machine (Standard edition will do. Just use this Google query on how to set up Win 2008 just like Vista and make it the ultimate workstation!

[Google Query](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=windows+server+2008+ultimate+workstation&meta=)

Comment: The only problem that leaves is getting the correct drivers. Also, would this effect my existing software? Eg visual studio 2008 - will all that run fine even in 64 bit mode?

Comment: Drivers will be the same as for VIsta x64, everything else will run perfectly, even x86 programs